# Looking for a shapefile of the US Southwest Border Sectors

Tags: data, united-states

I'm looking for a shapefile similar to the following image:

[image: Border Sectors]

I'd just like the outlines of the sectors. I'm only concentrating on the southwest border which is San Diego all the way to Rio Grande Valley, but I'm ok with data on all of the sectors.

Does anyone know where I can find something like this?